# How to add a class to tr, if one of its td's have some content.

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add a class to tr, if one of its td's have content. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Some content</td>
<td>Some content</td>
<td></td>
<td>Some content</td>
<td>Some content</td>
<td class="last"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Some content</td>
<td>Some content</td>
<td>Some content</td>
<td>Some content</td>
<td>Some content</td>
<td class="last">Some content</td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$('tr').each(function(){
if($('td.last').length > 0  {       
    $(this).addClass('someclass');
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/odpb3tg3/

Comment: If you really mean one of it's td have content $('tr').has('td:not(:empty)').addClass('someclass');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with **[:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** and **[:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** and **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** in a single line,

```
$('td.last:not(:empty)').closest('tr').addClass('someclass');
```

```js
$('td.last:not(:empty)').closest('tr').addClass('someclass')
```

```css
.someclass{color:red}
.someclass .last{color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td class="last"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td class="last">Some content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it effectively by using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/),

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
  return $('td.last', this).text().length > 0;
}).addClass("SomeClass");
```

And you have to traverse the `tds` based on this object.

Answer (score 2):

Use combination of **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** , **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** and **[`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** psedudo class selectors.

```
$('tr:has(td.last:not(:empty))').addClass('someclass');
```

```js
$('tr:has(td.last:not(:empty))').addClass('someclass');
```

```css
.someclass {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td class="last"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td class="last">Some content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code

```
$('tr').each(function(){
if($('td.last').length > 0  {       
    $(this).addClass('someclass');
}
});
```

To

```
$('tr').each(function() {
   if ($(this).find("td.last").text().length > 0) {
     $(this).addClass('someclass');
   }
});
```

You need to use `$(this).find("td.last").text()` instead of  `$('td.last')`

> [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odpb3tg3/3/)